# Radio button selection invisible to user when jQuery animation runs

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-events

I have a group of radio buttons that, when clicked, trigger an animation that hides the group and shows the next one. The problem I'm having is that the animation runs before the selection is visible to the user, which may be confusing. So, I'd like to wait for the screen to repaint the selection, and then animate the transition to the next group, but I have yet to find an elegant way to do this.

I created a fiddle that displays the effect (http://jsfiddle.net/DPnXB/), and for convenience I'll add the Javascript and html here as well.

```js
function init(){
  $(".panel.first").addClass("focus");
  $("input:radio").on("click", animate);
}
init();

function animate(){
  var currentPanel, nextPanel;

  currentPanel = $(this).parents(".panel");
  nextPanel = $(".panel").not(".focus").first();

  nextPanel.css({opacity: 0}).addClass("focus");
  currentPanel.removeClass("focus");
  nextPanel.animate({opacity: 1}, 300); 
}
```

```html
<div class="panel first">
  First panel
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1"/> option 1 </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1"/> option 2 </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup1"/> option 3 </label>
</div>
<div class="panel last">
  Last panel
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2"/> option 1 </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2"/> option 2 </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2"/> option 3 </label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="radioGroup2"/> option 4 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an "elegant" way, there are no other events that would be helpful, so I guess your best bet would be a short timeout before starting the animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/DPnXB/2/

Please note that i've changed they way the current panel is selected, this was neccessary because the scope of the `animate` function would no longer be the `input` element, but the `window` object!

And just in case it might be of any use, here's a slightly more modified version that can handle more than 2 groups correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/DPnXB/3/

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a timer. I think it's a fine solution. I actually wish I thought of it myself. Thanks!